# How to easily store variables to be used by Flask?

Tags: flask

I am writing a simple Flask web-app, where people can log in with a username, chose a role, and that pretty much is it. However, they must be able, if they log in again, to know what role they chose.

The natural idea would be to write a simple dict, but I understood that you just couldn't do that if you are outside development. I also read that the recommended solution was a database, but using MySQL etc seems to be way overkill for this task...

Is there a simpler way ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQLite with Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlite3/). It's much simpler than using a full-fledged database like MySQL.

Comment: I forgot to add that I am hosted on pythonanywhere, and that they do not provide a sqlite database... EDIT : just saw that sqlite was indeed serverless. Will dig into that !

Answer (score 0):

use flask-sqlalchemy. It's much simpler